# Problem with save image in ruby on rails using carrierwave and react image value is null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, image, file-upload, carrierwave

Dataflow from react to backend is okay, i have 204 status code. In console i see that image param is detect.

Started POST "/training" for ::1 at 2020-09-13 17:25:50 +0200
(0.1ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
Processing by TrainingController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"description"=>"test", "image"=>"data:image/png...(long message)

at the end these operation i see

```
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
↳ app/controllers/training_controller.rb:20:in `create'

Training Create (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "trainings" ("description", "image", "created_at", 
"updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["description", "test"], ["image", nil], ["created_at", 
"2020-09-13 15:25:50.715990"], ["updated_at", "2020-09-13 15:25:50.715990"]]

↳ app/controllers/training_controller.rb:20:in `create'
(3.9ms)  commit transaction

↳ app/controllers/training_controller.rb:20:in `create'
No template found for TrainingController#create, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 4.2ms | Allocations: 4126)
```

now we see that our object image is nil i dont know why.
Here is my training controller and image uploader

- Training Controller

  class TrainingController < ApplicationController

  ```
  before_action :set_training, only: [:show, :edit, :update]

  def index
      @training = Training.all
      Training.order("created_at DESC")
      render json: @training
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
      @training = Training.new
  end

  def create
      training = Training.new(training_params)
      training.save
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
      @training.update_attributes(training_params)
  end

  private

  def training_params
      params.require(:training).permit(:description, :image)
  end

  def set_training
      @training = Training.find(params[:id])
  end
  ```

end

- ImageUploader

```
  attr_accessor :description, :image
  storage :file
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end


what is bad?
```